# Как экспортировать sql-таблицу в файл на хостинге с помощью Php?

Tags: резервное-копирование, php, export, sql

Добрый день, поискал в гугле, не чего хорошего не нашел. 3 способа один из через "консоль" и 2 через запросы. Но к сожалению не вышло у меня найти как правильно экспортировать одну таблицу с синтаксисом sql. Кто знает готовый вариант, поделитесь пожалуйста. Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php